# How to hide my admin ID in Facebook Open Graph code

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am using Facebook Open Graph on several different projects that I'm managing and just realized that the code (meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxx") code can be used by pretty much anyone to track my identity by punching in the numeric user id into facebook.com/USER_ID.

Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Use an app ID as the admin, and add your user account as an admin of the app - users will see the app ID in the source, but can't retrieve a list of the admins of that app

Comment: The site is not an app, though, so I'm not sure it has an app number.  Pressing the like button adds a "like" to the site itself, not a Facebook page.

Comment: Use the meta tag to designate an App as the 'admin' of the page, use the admins of the app to actually access the insights,etc. The app itself doesn't need to do anything, just be a placeholder for delegating access

Comment: just to clarify, in order to get an app ID, I have to create a new app for each of the websites through the facebook's developers site, correct?

Comment: I have an additional question actually.  Before creating any of these web apps, I was able to access Insights for all of the sites once they passed 30 likes.  Insights seemed to include a multi-digit number for each site.  What's the purpose of that number, and will it be replaced with the new app number now?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No.

Longer Answer: No, you can not and this is by design.

If you are not OK with letting people know who you are, may I ask why you are using a system like FB that was created to be very specific and detail you as a person in order to better leverage the advertisement system it is built around that funds its existence?

Comment: Are you getting this information from a source that's perhaps not available to the public? This is the first time I'm hearing that Facebook was built around profiling website administrators.